# Forward log to http server

Tags: linux, http, ubuntu

I have a pipeline that I run with nextflow which is a workflow framework.
It has an option of seeing real time logs on the http server.
The command to do this is like so:

nextflow run script.nf --with-weblog http://localhost:8891

But I don't see anything when I open my web browser. I have port forwarded while logging into the ubuntu instance and the python http server seems to work fine.

I will need help in understanding how I can set this up so I can view logs generated by my script on the url provided.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In nextflow you need to be careful with the leading dashes of commandline parameters. Everything starting with two dashes like `--input` will be forwarded to your workflow/processes (e.g. as `params.input`) while parameters with a single leading dash like `-entry` are interpreted as parameters by nextflow.

It might be a typo in your question, but to make this work you have to use `-with-weblog <url>` (note that I used only a single dash here)

See the corresponding [docs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/tracing.html#weblog-via-http) for further information on this:

> Nextflow is able to send detailed workflow execution metadata and
> runtime statistics to a HTTP endpoint. To enable this feature use the
> -with-weblog as shown below:

> `nextflow run <pipeline name> -with-weblog [url]`

However, this might not be the only problem you are encountering with your setting. You will have to store or process the webhooks that nextflow sends on the server.

P.S: since this is already an old question, how did you proceed? Have you solved that issue yourself in the meantime or gave up on it?